# angular fullcalendar: open custom popup from the calendar

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, ng-bootstrap

I'm using fullcalendar v4 (https://fullcalendar.io/) with angular.

I have a custom button in my header, when I click on it I want a popup to open. Popups are handled by ng-bootstrap.

Here is this button that I set as a property of my fullcalendar:

```
customButtons = {
    settings: {
      bootstrapFontAwesome: 'fa-cogs',
      click: function () {
        this.openPopup();
      }
    }
  };
```

The button is correctly loaded to the fullcalendar component. However when I click on it I get

```
ERROR TypeError: this.openPopup is not a function
```

I'm getting this error because full-calendar is another component and this.openPopup() is located in the parent component.

Here is my question:

Is there a way to @Output() an event from full-calendar? This way I could triger my function in the parent component.

If not, I was thinking about loading all the logic into the button, but I'm using a service and external dependy for that. Can they be loaded into the full-calendar?

Comment: You could use Observable for it! Or follow this link: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/624